# JavaFX - ListView<? extends V> - Generics - CellFactory

Tags: java, generics, javafx, cell-formatting

I have:

```
public abstract class V {}

public class PV extends V {}

public class TV extends V {}
```

I also have:

```
ListView<? extends V> listView = new ListView<>();
```

When I try:

```
listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<? extends V>, ListCell<? extends V>>() {
        @Override
        .............
    });
```

I get error warning:

```
Incompatible types: 
anonymous Callback<ListView<? extends V>, ListCell<? extends V>>
cannot be converted to Callback<ListView<CAP#1>, ListCell<CAP#!>>
where CAP#1 is fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends V from capture of ? extends V
```

I tried:

```
new Callback<ListView<V>, ListCell<V>>()
```

That did not solve this problem.

Why do I get that message and is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to achieve here? It's hard to see how you would not know what kind of `ListView` you were creating, unless you are writing a general reusable component that contained the list view. In that case, just make the component generic (`MyComponent<T extends V>`) and then create a `ListView<T>`. (Also, did you mean `ListView<? extends V> listView = new ListView<>()` in the second code block?)

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you use a lamdba you can get away with this in a way you can't if you declare the type explicitly. `listView.setCellFactory(param -> { return new ListCell<>(); });`

Comment: Also, did you mean ListView<? extends V> listView = new ListView<>() in the second code block?    YES, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The `cellFactory` needs a `Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>>` where `T` is the type parameter of `ListView`.

Using a wildcard you cannot specify the exact type parameter. Furthermore since your wildcard restricts `T` to supertypes of `V` you cannot use `ListCell<? extends V>` (even if the exact type wouldn't be a requirement, `updateItem` receives a value matching the type parameter of `ListCell`, it's there's no guarantee the type is assignable (The exact type parameter of the `ListView` could be `Object` and the one of `ListView` could be `PV`)).

You could create a method for creating the `Callback` though to prevent the wildcard from being an issue, however a `super` restriction still makes little sense, since `ListCell` acts as consumer.

```
public static <T> Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>> forListView() {
    return new Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<T> call(ListView<T> lv) {
            return new ListCell<T>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    setText((empty || item == null) ? "" : item.toString());
                }

            };
        }
    };
}
```

```
ListView<? super V> lv = ...;
lv.setCellFactory(forListView());
```

(You could impose restrictions on `T` of the static method too: `public static <T super V> Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>> forListView()`)